# Singleton access performance

Tags: java, android

Whenever I want to use singleton pattern in my app code I use similar code to this:

```
public class Singleton {

    private volatile static Singleton INSTANCE;

    public static synchronized Singleton singleton() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new Singleton();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

I think it's quite common solution, but now I'm wondering what's the best way to use that singleton instance, whether using it as inline function:

```
singleton().doSomething();
singleton().doSomethingElse();
```

or create singleton field in every class which uses it:

```
private Singleton mSingleton = singleton(); // Or pass it in constructor

mSingleton.doSomething();
mSingleton.doSomethingElse();
```

**Question**

In which case performance is better?

Comment: Singleton Instance is mostly used to create 'Single' instance through-out APP like Datebase,Network,SharePreference etc. Now days you can also use Dagger to achieve Singleton Instance.

Comment: Unless you're experiencing an actual performance problem that can be traced back to this singleton, this is a waste of time. One of the leading causes of Bad Code is looking for solutions where there are no problems.

Comment: The documented best practice for singletons in Java is to implement them with single-constant enums: `public enum Singular { SINGULAR; }` One adds whatever behavior to that, of course. "Performance" would depend on two things: what state and behaviors the type sports, and what you measure as "performance".

Answer (score -1):

## Do not use the Singelton Pattern!

A *Singelton* is merely a *global variable* and makes your code inflexible, hart to reuse and hard to test.

Make your Singeltons ordinary objects and ensure that there is only one instance when constructing the object tree either by passing around the one and only instance of the logical singelton  or by using a *dependency injection framework*.

---

> You went off on a tangent and forgot to answer the question. – shmosel

## Do not choose certain syntax for performance!

There is no point of choosing a certain syntax for performance reason especially in a *managed language* like Java.

The JVM will modify and optimize the resulting byte code when executing is and it may even recompile it to machine code. This makes it impossible to judge the performance impact of a certain syntax.

Even if the syntax chosen *had* any performance effect, would it be recognizable? Changes in syntax can change performance only in fractions. But to recognize a difference it muts be more than 50% (20% when having both versions running in parallel).

Both aspects make any considerations of performance effects of syntax useless. Don't think of performance unless you have *experienced * a problem an **proven by measurement** that the code in question really it the bottleneck. Anything else is considered *premature optimization*.

Choose your syntax so that it *expresses your intent* an makes your code best readable.

Comment: I have seen this comment in almost anywhere. I am wondering why big companies mostly use singleton pattern such as Firebase api from Google etc... And i think dependency injection is unusable in Android platform in most cases

Comment: *"I am wondering why big companies mostly use singleton pattern"* it is ease and fast to use. And size does not relate to quality in any way.

Comment: You went off on a tangent and forgot to answer the question.

Answer (score -3):

In case of Singleton performance will be better because if you create same object many times to perform same task it will take memory in heap. it consume heap memory. So if you can do a task by using only one object then why create many object.